# Unexpected foreign key generated for one to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-fluent-api

I have declared two classes - Person and Vehicle as shown below

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.Vehicles = new HashSet<Vehicle>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required, MaxLength(10)]
    public string MobileNo1 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string MobileNo2 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Email1 { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Email2 { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string VehicleNumber { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VehicleOwner")]
    public int? VehicleOwnerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VehicleOwnerID")]
    public virtual Person VehicleOwner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("VehicleDriver")]
    public int? VehicleDriverID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VehicleDriverID")]
    public virtual Person VehicleDriver { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int? PersonID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

}
```

This generates two foreign keys on Vehicles table as

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Person", t => t.PersonID)
.ForeignKey("dbo.Person", t => t.Person_PersonID)
```

whereas what i expect is only

```
.ForeignKey("dbo.Person", t => t.PersonID)
```

Initially i thought it might be because i missed out declaring the entities as virtual but that was not the case. I am not able to detect the problem with this code.

Like Vehicles, i have another class - Documents with somewhat the same structure and relationship with Person. But for Documents the foreign key is generated as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got 3 classes pointing at Person, so configure as:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [Key]
    public int VehicleID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string VehicleNumber { get; set; }

    public int? VehicleOwnerID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VehicleOwnerID")]
    public virtual Person VehicleOwner { get; set; }

    public int? VehicleDriverID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("VehicleDriverID")]
    public virtual Person VehicleDriver { get; set; }

    public int? PersonID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PersonID")]
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

}
```

While that is incorrect syntax, the 2nd foreign key comes from the collection of vehicles on the person and EF not being able to resolve which FK it belongs to.

So in your Person class on your collection you need to point to the corresponding nav in the vehicle:

```
[InverseProperty("Person")]
public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
```

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inverseproperty-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I think this might do it.. Let me try it out and get back

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to model, but if you are just trying to track Drivers and Owners you should have 2 collections on Person (VehiclesOwned, VehiclesDriven) with an InverseProperty attribute on each.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve has said, this is because you have references to Person from your vehicle class. So, Entity Framework creates 3 keys one for Person, VehicleOwner, and VehicleDriver. Yet, it creates another key because of the collection of vehicles from person. You must use the inverse property attribute here to tell Entity Framework that you mean to build a relationship between Vehicle and Person on the actual Vehicle.Person property. You can do this by

```
[InverseProperty("Person")]
public virtual ICollection<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
```

Also, you being redundant with:

```
[ForeignKey("Person")]
public int? PersonID { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PersonID")]
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
```

Remove the ForeignKey from the int? PersonID in your Vehicle class.

Comment: Redundant, but the collection is what causes the Person_PersonID to be added.

Comment: @Jared I tried ur solution but still get the same issue

Comment: @MufaddalGulshan I see more of your issue now. It's because of what steve is saying.